# Create VM in Azure with powershell with no public IP

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-public-ip

I'm creating VM on Azure from an Image using powershell.

This is the script I'm using .

```
$UserName = "username"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password@123" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)    
New-AzureRmVm `
    -ResourceGroupName "RSG" `
    -Name "VMName" `
    -ImageName "ImageName" `
    -Location "West US" `
    -VirtualNetworkName "VNName" `
    -SubnetName "default" `
    -Credential $psCred
    -PublicIpAddressName "None" `
    -OpenPorts 3389
```

But, when I got into the Azure portal and see, some Public Ip is getting assigned by default. I have also tried without giving `PublicIpAddressName` property assuming , it wont assign any IP, but still it is assigning.

I want the Public IP to be none.Can anyone help me achieve this.Thanks!

Comment: Actually, "None" means you do not specify the name and it's the default value. Azure will provide a name for it.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT, so how to make it blank?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems you cannot create a vm without public IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this an issue which is still in **Open** state on official `azure-powershell` github. You can refer it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/5342) . Incase if you still want to bypass this you can try using `New-AzureReservedIP` or after the deployment command try to remove the public ip by yourself `Remove-AzureRmPublicIpAddress`.

**Note** : I have'nt tested it yet. Just an idea.

Refer : [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/remove-azurermpublicipaddress?view=azurermps-6.7.0)

Answer (score 0):

To set no public ip address you have can just define it as "" , in powershell you will need to quote that again so it will be """" .

Comment: This is not true. I have actually tried it (however stupidly this advice sounded), using `New-AzVM ... -PublicIpAddressName """" ...` and I've got the error: `New-AzVM : Resource name " is invalid. The name can be up to 80 characters long. It must begin with a word character, a
nd it must end with a word character or with '_'. The name may contain word characters or '.', '-', '_'.`
It also doesn't work when the name is specified as `'""'`.
Maybe it works with `az` command, but not for PowerShell cmdlet.

Comment: this was a bug that has probably been fixed then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell, then you will need to escape all empty parameters by changing "" to '""' to properly pass an empty string into the command. Without this, PowerShell will not pass the empty string, and you will get an error from the command indicating it's missing a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$winVmCred = Get-Credential `
  -Message "Enter username and password for the Windows management virtual machine."

# Create a NIC for the VM.
$winVmNic = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name "winVMNIC01" `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName `
  -Location $location `
  -SubnetId $targetVMSubnet.Id `
  -PrivateIpAddress "10.10.12.10"

# Configure the Windows management VM.
$winVmConfig = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $winVmName -VMSize $winVmSize | `
Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName $winVmName -Credential $winVmCred | `
Set-AzVMSourceImage -PublisherName $winVmPublisher `
  -Offer $winVmOffer `
  -Skus $winVmSku `
  -Version $winVmVersion | `
  Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -Id $winVmNic.Id

# Create the VM.
$winVM = New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName `
  -Location $location `
  -VM $winVmConfig `
  -ErrorAction Stop
```